# Why does SVG text appear to bounce as I animate it along path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, svg

I have an svg `<path ...>` and `<textPath ...>` that I animate by re-setting the text's startoffset property in a `setTimeout( ...)` routine.

Please see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEN6et5Qjztsg56Rlrhr?p=preview) to see the jumpy text and code (it is too much code to show here).

NOTE: I am using angular in the code snippet.

*(ALSO ... if anyone wishes to suggest a better way of doing this, I would appreciate it ... thanks.)*

Comment: It doesn't look jumpy to me, so I suspect it's just that your computer isn't fast enough. I have no solution for you though.

Comment: interesting ... I just checked it on iphone (safari), and it was smooth ... what browser were you using ...

Comment: SMIL: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/textpath1.svg

Comment: I've looked at it on chrome for windows and android. Smooth in both cases.